# Appending a TextView

Tags: android

I have an app which at current will on the press of a button eg. the number 1 button change a text view to have the number 1 in it. What i need to do is append the view so that say when the number 3 is pressed the text view will say 13 instea of just 3. Here is the switch statement i'm using to handle the button presses.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View c) {

    switch (c.getId()) 
    {
        case R.id.keypad_1:
            TextView prs1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diff);
            prs1.setText("1");

    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you leave this method empty? This way you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the [TextView.append()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [append()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)) method of textView and the difference between setText and append can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353992/difference-between-settext-and-append). If you make the following changes I think the code would work as expected.

```
TextView prs1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diff);
public void onClick(View c){
    switch (c.getId()) 
    {
        case R.id.keypad_1:
            prs1.append("1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try doing this:

```
prs1.setText(prs1.getText() + "1");
```

Edit: Sorry I just realized you wanted it to say "13"

So you would want to do this:

```
String text = prs1.getText();
prs1.setText("1" + text);
```

"when the screen first comes up there is a ? in the text view, then when i press the 1 button i want the text view to be 1 then when i press 3 it would need to be 13.":

Do this then:

```
String text = prs1.getText();
if(text.contains("?"))
            text = text.replace("?", "");
    prs1.setText("1" + text);
```