# How append to textview & remove last letter from textview?

Tags: android, textview

I want to add text in textview in android, but when the backspace is pressed the last character should be removed.

- I am **using softkeyboard**.
- I am **creating textview dynamically**.
- and **update textview when key of soft-keyboard is dispatched/pressed**.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent KEvent){
     keyaction = KEvent.getAction();

    if(keyaction == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
         keycode = KEvent.getKeyCode();
         keyunicode = KEvent.getUnicodeChar(KEvent.getMetaState() );
         character = (char) keyunicode;
        textView.setText(""+character);
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(KEvent);
}
```

Every time I press a key, textview is set with a new character and **previous one gets overridden.**
**Also if backspace is pressed than last character appended get deleted**

Is there any way to do this to textview?

Comment: you can use textView.append(character)

Comment: thanks saeed . but If we press backspace then character that we append most recently does not deleted from textview.

Comment: what is your actual problem ... ... not deleted last character  when you back pressed .. you want also delete  that.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
textView.append("" + character);
```

Or

```
textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + character);
```

This is the doc for [TextView.append()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence))

It seems it may cause an extra padding in your TextView() as described (and fixed) by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353992/difference-between-settext-and-append).

You may want to check it also.

**UPDATE**

To detect backspace:

You may want to add some security checks (like string length and different null etc)

```
if(keyaction == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
    if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
        // Remove last char from string (like backspace would do)
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString().substring(0, textView.getText().length() - 1));
    } else {
        textView.append("" + character);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks . but If we press backspace then character that we append most recently does not deleted from textview.

Comment: @sakshamagarwal I suggest you debug your app, but seems that you are trying to append the backspace character

Comment: @sakshamagarwal I upadted the answer... let me know if it works.

Comment: @sakshamagarwal I updated again. I tested and it works. KEYCODE_DEL =67. After input that event, string is deleted.

Comment: @sakshamagarwal Are you using a soft keyboard? Maybe, that's why is not working... check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event

Comment: I am using soft keyboard but thanks it is working now...!!

Comment: Great... Good to hear