# How do I repeat the same text after clicking a button?

Tags: android, android-studio, calculator

I'm trying to make a simple calculator in Android Studio, and I'm having trouble repeating the same number in text view.

For example, if I press 1 on the calculator, it will show the number 1 on top, but if I press it again, nothing happens.

Therefore, I can't make numbers greater than 9.

Here's my code:

```css
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button0);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
                tv.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                tv.setText("0");
            }
        });

        btn = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
                tv.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                tv.setText("1");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your code as text instead of screenshot of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `textViewObj.setText("1");` will always replace the existing text in the view. Based on your description of the requirement, `textViewObj.append("1");` should be the one which can achieve it.

Replace `textViewObj.setText("1");` with `textViewObj.append("1");` appropriately, as follows

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            tv.append("1");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Do you think you could show an example because I'm still a little confused on this?

Comment: @RayaanAfzal no problem. Remember to mark answer as accepted, so that others can benefit too.

Answer (score 0):

**btn** is the button you clicked:

```
btn.setOnClickListener((view)->{
String currentNumber = txtViewObj.getText().toString();
String number =  ((TextView)view).getText().toString(); //I assume that you already named each button corresponding to its number, for example button1 call it 1, button2 call it 2
txtViewObj.setText(currentNumber+number);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what exactly happens is that using `textView.setText("1")` each time will destroy the TextView's buffer containing any text and simply replace it with the new text i.e. `"1"` and using `textView.append("1")` will update the buffer of the TextView to display the concatenated text. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353992/difference-between-settext-and-append) answer for more details.